Authenticate with Xero Connected App got undefined with CallbackParams
I created an OAuth2 flow with a Xero Connected App, and it was working fine.
The workflow is as follows:

When a user clicks a link like https://server-domain/xero/auth?url=some_redirect_link, they are redirected to the Xero authentication page to log in. The url param will be stored in express session.

After the user logged in, they are redirected back to my server via the callback URL https://server-domain/xero/callback. I got the url param from the express session, and then redirect one more time to that url.


Recently, I encountered an error like this: When I clicked on the authentication URL /xero/auth, it redirected to Xero. After logging in, it redirected to my server and return the following error instead of redirecting to the specified some_redirect_link in the parameter:
{“response:{},”status”:400,”options”:{},”message”:”Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘callbackParams’)”,”name”:”BadRequestException”)

I use NestJS.
Here is my xero.controller.ts file:
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { XeroClient } from 'xero-node';

@Controller('xero')
export class XeroIntegrationController {
  private xeroClient: XeroClient;
  constructor(
    private readonly xeroService: XeroIntegrationService
  ) {
    this.xeroClient = new XeroClient({clientId: ..., clientSecret: ..., redirectUris, scopes});
  }

  @Get('auth')
  async authenticate(
    @Query('url') url: string,
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ) {
    req.session.url = url;

    // Redirect to Xero OAuth2 flow
    const authUrl = await this.xeroClient.buildConsentUrl();
    res.redirect(authUrl);
  }

  @Get('callback')
  async callback(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
    // Handle OAuth2 callback
    try {
      const { activeTenant } = await this.xeroService.exchangeCodeForToken(req);

      res.redirect(
        `${req.session.url}`,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException(error);
    }
  }
}

In my xero.service.ts file:
async exchangeCodeForToken(
    req: Request,
  ): Promise<{ tokenSet: TokenSet; activeTenant: ITenant }> {
    try {
      const tokenSet: TokenSet = await this.xeroClient.apiCallback(req.url);

      await this.xeroClient.updateTenants(false);

      return { tokenSet, activeTenant: this.xeroClient.tenants[0] };
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(
        'Failed to exchange authorization code for token',
        error,
      );
      throw new BadRequestException(error);
    }
  }

However, after redeploying the server without making any code changes, the issue resolved itself.
I am concerned that this issue might happen again, so I would like to understand the reason to fix it properly. Thank you.

I found a similar issue in another post. However, it didn't explain why my code was working fine and then suddenly encountered this error. After redeploying, the error disappeared.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287638/xero-node-undefined-call-back-params?rq=2
